# Adding a div on each instance of occurence using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have repeating divs that contain certain information and in particular dates. I have written a function that extracts the day from the date and inserts another div showing this day. However, I am trying to get this to work for all repeating divs. My code only shows the day for the first instance e.g

```
<div class="am-event-sub-info">
<div class="am-event-sub-info-capacity"><img src=""> Capacity: 0 / 
100</div>
<!---->
<div class="day">Saturday</div>

<div class="am-event-sub-info">
<div class="am-event-sub-info-capacity"><img src=""> Capacity: 0 / 
100</div>
<!---->
<div class="day">Sunday</div>
```

```js
var container= $('.am-event-info');
for (var i = 0; i < container.length; i++) { 


var day = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
        weekday: 'long'
      }).format(
        new Date(
        $(".am-event-info").find('.am-event-sub-info:eq(1)').text().trim().split(' - ')[0].replace("th","") // only interested in the "February 27, 2021 11:30 am" part 
        )
      )


                document.querySelector('.am-event-sub-info').innerHTML += '<div class="day">'+day+'</div>';
            }
```

```css
.am-event-info {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1xp solid white;
  background: #c5c5c5;
  margin: 10px;
}
.day{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="am-events-booking">

  <div class="am-event-info">
    <div class="am-event-sub-info">
      <div class="am-event-sub-info-capacity"><img src=""> Capacity: 0 / 100</div>
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div class="am-event-sub-info">
      <div><img src="">February 27th, 2021 11:30 am - 1:00 pm</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="am-event-info">
    <div class="am-event-sub-info">
      <div class="am-event-sub-info-capacity"><img src=""> Capacity: 0 / 100</div>
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div class="am-event-sub-info">
      <div><img src="">February 28th, 2021 11:30 am - 1:00 pm</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="am-event-info">
    <div class="am-event-sub-info">
      <div class="am-event-sub-info-capacity"><img src=""> Capacity: 0 / 100</div>
      <!---->
    </div>
    <div class="am-event-sub-info">
      <div><img src="">March 1st, 2021 11:30 am - 1:00 pm</div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: _“However, I am trying to get this to work for all repeating divs.”_ - I don’t see any try, so - _show us_ what you tried, please.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: There is no point in that `for` loop, because inside, you are accessing the same element each time - so you are only overwriting the same output multiple times.

Comment: This should start with a loop over the `.am-event-info` elements. Then, inside the loop, you find the second `.am-event-sub-info` element inside the current element, to get your date value, and then you write the result of your data manipulation into the second `.am-event-sub-info` found in the current parent element (if that’s where you want it? Your explanation is rather ambiguous, and code that makes little sense to begin with, is not helpful in clearing that up either.)

Comment: @CBroe I have added the loop over the `am-event-info` element however it still only shows up in the first div. Yes I want to write the result in the second `.am-event-sub-info` found in my current element.

Comment: That’s because you are still using `$(".am-event-info").find()` inside the loop, and that will only apply the method to the first element in that selection. You are alternating between jQuery and vanilla JavaScript syntax a lot here, this will be easier if you stick to jQuery. Use the `each` method it provides to loop over the elements, then inside the loop callback function, `$(this)` will refer to the current element, so you can start `.find()`-ing the sub-elements from there then.